# Is there a more secure means of authentication than Forms authentication

Tags: security, authentication, cookies, forms-authentication

I was wondering if there is a more secure way of authenticating than forms authentication? I don't like the fact that when you login to a site using forms authentication, you can copy the cookie to another computer, and log in. I realise that if the site is browsed to over ssl there can be no man in the middle attack, however I still don't like the fact my site is vulnerable in this way.

Is there a good alternative available, other than windows authentication?

Thanks

Comment: Short-lived Web tokens help mitigate the risk posed by copying cookies as the typically don't include encrypted username and passwords and they become invalidated after a short amount of time so even if they were stolen they would not be able to be used...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look into token-based stuff, but what you will find is that there is always *something* that is stored on the client and passed for authentication instead of the actual user credentials (username and password). Whether it's a session id or a token does not really matter if you assume the attacker has the ability to access stuff on the client.

When token-based auth is used, the tokens are most of the times not kept in a cookie, but for example in browser memory (Javascript objects), or even worse, in places like localStorage. That is actually *less secure* than a good old session id in an httpOnly cookie, which is secure against cross-site scripting, as opposed to pretty much anything else in a browser.

So do realize that with almost any solution you choose, basically what happens is you exchange your user credentials for some kind of a token which you then use for authentication, and for the session the token is equivalent to your credentials, and there is not much difference between traditional sessions and tokens. Even Windows auth does about the same, but a layer below, on the OS level, which makes it less susceptible to attacks like XSS, but makes it vulnerable to attacks based on automatically sent session ids (like CSRF).

If you want to mitigate the threat of an attacker stealing session ids, you can for example design your application in a way that sessions are bound to client identifiers like the client ip address. That way even if a session id is stolen, the attacker still cannot use it. As another mitigation to that threat, you can prevent concurrent sessions, practically meaning logic around terminating all other sessions of a user that logs in. Note that these things are not specific to traditional sessions, the same applies to token-based auth, only the implementation is different.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I decided to go with forms authentication, but I might add the IP address, or something else to the cookie to prevent multiple logins from different computers using the same cookie